# Backbone. Render/Reset filtered collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im having trouble with a render function. The function takes an array as parameter an returns new models of the collection. But it only renders once. I run it on a click and the collection itself listen to "change". The problem is that the collection does not get the new items.

I think its the reset function that is the problem. But i don't know how to do it in another way. Basically i just want to remove all previous models and set the new ones. How would i do that?

Thanks!

```
filter: function(f) {

    var filter = this.collection.filter(function(o){ 
        var accept = false;                                    
        $(f).each(function(i,val){
            if(_.indexOf(o.get('tags'), val) >-1){
                accept = true;                      
            }
        })
        return accept; 
    });

    this.collection.reset(filter);

    new PeopleView({
        el: this.$('.list'),
        collection: this.collection
    });

},
```

PeopleView render:

```
PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html('');
    this.collection.each(this.renderPerson, this);
    this.listenTo(this.collection,'change',this.render);
},

renderPerson: function (person) {
    this.$el.append(new PersonView({
        tagName: 'li',
        id:'p_'+person.get('id'),
        model: person
    }).el);
},
```

});

Comment: I have also tried to use "set" instead of "reset". Does not work either. this.collection.set(filter);

Comment: I don't see a `render` method defined here.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. But the "Peopleview" render itself. Just takes the collection in as a param/option.

Comment: Where is the code for `PeopleView`? `render` is, by default, a `noop`.

Comment: Edited my post and added the render.

Comment: Is the `change` event firing on the collection? You can do `this.listenTo(this.collection,'all',function(obj, event) { console.log(event);});` to see which events are firing.

Comment: yes, the "change" is firing. The problem (i think) is the "reset" in my filter function. It only changes the collections models once. Maybe "reset" is not the way to go?

Comment: There are serveral issues: You missed to call `render()` after `new PersonView()`. On your `reset()` issue: you'll need to listen to the `reset` or `add` event, `change` fires on attribute change, not on add/reset. Your `filter()` method looks scary to me. `$(f).each()`: what is `f`? My opnion: I wouldn't reset the collection on which you've just been filterering on reset with the found models. It might work but have kind of master-slave collection (filtering on master into slave) would be a better thing.

Comment: More on the `$(f).each()`: I guess it will/should contain tag names to filter for. Why are you enumerating them with every model? Do it outside the `collection.each()` and use [_.intersection()](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#intersection)  Why don't you define `tagName` and `id` within the view itself (it workds this way, but putting it into the view will make the code look cleaner).

Comment: oh, nice and long comment there! The "f" is just ana array congaing which models to render. Could you show how i should do it with some code maybe?

Comment: @try-catch-finally render() is called from within PersonView. $(f) is the array holding wich models to render.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Thank for your help. I finally manage to get this going. I did as you said and just creating a slave collection whenever the filter changes and render that one instead of manipulating the master collection. By doing that i can skip the events as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simpler version of this on code pen and got it working (no view and filters criteria is hard coded) but the principle seems the same

the main difference is that it listens for a "reset" event on my collection seeing as that is what you are asking the collection to do. [You can see it here](http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/onzLx), just have your console open to see the results

```
var PeopleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PeopleModel
});

var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection([{
    id: 1,
    name: "jim"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "fred"
}]);

//listen for restet
peopleCollection.on("reset", function() {
    console.log("people reset");
    console.log(peopleCollection.models);
});

var filter = peopleCollection.filter(function(o) {
    var accept = false;
    $(['i']).each(function(i, val) {
        if (_.indexOf(o.get('name'), val) > -1) {
            accept = true;
        }
    });
    return accept;
});
console.log("people:",peopleCollection);//this will print that the collection has two models
peopleCollection.reset(filter); //now i have rest with the filter the log will show only one model
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove set of model from collection try below simple solution

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove

```
that.collection.remove(filter);
```